# Link as submit button with name attribute

Tags: javascript, html, button, anchor

I'd like to use link as submit button but **with name attribute (e.g. name="submit")**.

Actual structure as button

`<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>`

What is the equivalent of that in link using java script?

It can be done by something like this

`<a href="javascript:document.yourform.submit();">Button</a>`

But no name attribute. I need name attribute work in link button for some reason.

Comment: That is not possible. What do you mean by "for some reason"?

Comment: I need to identify what button is clicked for my (PHP) back-end to identify which action should take. I used bootstrap dropdown button and it uses anchor.

Comment: You can put a name attribute to the a tag. HTML doesn't mind. Unless you want to explain what exactly you want

Comment: I have multiple link buttons and I want it to have name attribute for my (PHP) back-end to identify which action should take.

Comment: Create a hidden field name it as action. In the Submit link populate the hidden field value as Submit. And you can check value of input hidden (name=action,value=submit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hidden field name it as action. In the Submit link populate the hidden field value as Submit. And you can check value of input hidden (name=action,value=submit)

```
//JS function to set the hidden param
function doAction(action){
    document.getElementById('action').value=action;
}

//HTML Form
<form ...>
    <input type=hidden name="action" id="action" />
    <a href="javascript:doAction('submit');document.yourform.submit();">Submit</a>
    <a href="javascript:doAction('Update');CallSomeOther();">Update</a>

</form>

//Inside PHP
<?php
    $action = $_POST["action"];
    //do something
?>
```

Hope it helps!